# Is there a way to relax TypeScript compiler warning TS2339?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-construction

I am using the TypeScript compiler to check my JavaScript code as well. The reason for this is to find possible defects as early as possible. One of the compiler warnings of the TypeScript compiler is TS2339. It checks whether a type has defined a certain property. Since this can easily go wrong in JavaScript, this is a valuable compiler warning. For instance, suppose I have the following type:

```
mycar = {

  color: "green",

  topspeed: 180

};
```

and I am using somewhere in my code

```
c = mycar.colour;
```

I will get a warning that "colour" doesn't exist (typo). This would have gone unnoticed if I didn't have run the TypeScript compiler. So far so good.

But suppose you have the following JavaScript code, which is a common way of doing things in JavaScript:

```
mycar = {};

mycar.color = "green";

mycar.topspeed = 180;
```

If you run the TypeScript compiler then you will get

```
error TS2339: Property 'color' does not exist on type 'mycar'
```

Strictly speaking the TypeScript compiler is right, but actually nothing
can go wrong here. You might argue why I didn't  write the code as the
first example, but this is not common in JavaScript and moreover in
reality these data structures are far more complicated and in such a
case the latter way of coding is regarded as more convenient.

So my question is: is there a possibility to relax the TypeScript
compiler warning TS2339 to only spot the real issues?

Answer (score 1):

I think this chapter of wonderful Typescript book by Basarat might answer your question better than I am. It is quite short and 100% on point

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/lazyobjectliteralinitialization

Comment: Thanks, this is basically the same answer as Jonas Wilms has given. The book describes indeed exactly this situation, but none of the solutions proposed answers my question. The first one is just suppressing the TypeScript compiler warning for a type and the other one is following the TypeScript idiom instead of the JavaScript idiom. The latter is an improvement but this won't work in case you have complex types and/or a large code base that doesn't comply with this.

Comment: `The latter is an improvement but this won't work in case you have complex types and/or a large code base that doesn't comply with this` could you elaborate on this? I don't see any flaws there

Comment: Concerning your comment. If a code base contains lots of declarations like "mycar" in my original description, it will be a lot of work to rewrite all these incorrect declarations.

Answer (score 1):

How is Typescript supposed to know where the *real issues* are and which *you know of*? It actually works the other way round, you can tell typescript at which places it should not safeguard you:

```
  mycar = {} as any;
```

Or you could also *work with the compiler* and properly type the variable:

```
  let mycar: { color: number, /*...*/ };
```

Comment: Thanks but none of these solutions answers my question. The first one basically suppresses the TS2339 warning for all uses of "mycar", which I don't want. And the second one is what I described as being not the JavaScript way of doing things. I need something inbetween.