# Notion API gives an error for type candidate

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

The code that is causing the problem is the code below

```
import {Client, LogLevel} from "@notionhq/client";

const notion = new Client({
    auth: process.env.NOTION_TOKEN,
    logLevel: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? LogLevel.DEBUG : undefined
});

export const getPage = async (pageId:string) => {
    const response = await notion.pages.retrieve({ page_id: pageId });

    // ↓ Error this Line !!!
    const pageTitle = response.properties.Name.title[0].plain_text;
    console.log(pageTitle);
    return response;
};
```

When using the notion-API to retrieve blocks, the
I get an error like the one above and cannot get the property correctly.
The type is treated as any, which causes an error in the editor, but can be retrieved correctly in the browser.

How can I get rid of the error in the editor?

This problem could also be a problem with the editor or typescript.
Please give me some hints ️.

Thanks for answering before I did!

```
Property 'properties' does not exist on type 'GetPageResponse'.
  Property 'properties' does not exist on type '{ object: "page"; id: string; }'.ts(2339)
```

The main environment looks like this

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "notion-api-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "typelint": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.7.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@notionhq/client": "^0.4.12",
    "firebase": "^9.6.3",
    "framer-motion": "^5.6.0",
    "next": "12.0.8",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "recoil": "^0.5.2",
    "swr": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.0",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "focus-visible": "^5.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

```
// vscode

Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:38:17.605Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.1.0
```

```
node --version
v16.8.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a type definition of `GetPageResponse` from `node_modules\@notionhq\client\build\src\api-endpoints.d.ts`:

```
export declare type GetPageResponse = {
    parent: {
        type: "database_id";
        database_id: IdRequest;
    } | {
        type: "page_id";
        page_id: IdRequest;
    } | {
        type: "workspace";
        workspace: true;
    };
    properties: Record<string, {
        type: "title";
        title: Array<{
           ...
```

At first glance, you can see that it has `properties: Record<string, {...}>`, so what's the matter, right?

The problem is that it's only present in one of the two possible definitions of that type. See this simplified version:

```
export declare type GetPageResponse = {
    parent: {/*...*/};
    properties: Record<string, {/*...*/}>;
    /* ... */
} | {
    object: "page";
    id: string;
};
```

As you can see, `GetPageResponse` can also be of type `{ object: "page"; id: string; }`, and this type doesn't have `properties`.

So, you have to make sure that property exists first, like so:

```
if ("properties" in response) {
  const pageTitle = response.properties.Name.title[0].plain_text;
  console.log(pageTitle);
  return response;
}
```

Full compiling code may look like this:

```
import { Client, LogLevel } from "@notionhq/client";

const notion = new Client({
  auth: process.env.NOTION_TOKEN,
  logLevel: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? LogLevel.DEBUG : undefined,
});

export const getPage = async (pageId: string) => {
  const response = await notion.pages.retrieve({ page_id: pageId });

  if ("properties" in response) {
    if ("title" in response.properties.Name) {
      const pageTitle = response.properties.Name.title[0].plain_text;
      console.log(pageTitle);
      return response;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!
That code stopped the error!

That's a workaround for now, but I was wondering if there's a way to tweak the settings or something to make it work without this description?

Comment: That's another question, see [Is there a way to relax TypeScript compiler warning TS2339?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765104/is-there-a-way-to-relax-typescript-compiler-warning-ts2339). TL;DR, you can use `as any` but that'd kinda defeat the purpose of using TypeScript. Please mark answers as accepted if they solved your problem, thanks!